# Setup dynamic logging with Microsoft's dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a self-taught programmer, so I'm finding this a little difficult. I'm trying to create a logger class dynamically, let me explain. Each class gets a ILogger instance, which is really just ConsoleLogger.

```
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public ConsoleLogger(Type classType)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm currently doing it.

```
this.AddSingleton<ILogger, ConsoleLogger>(provider =>
    new ConsoleLogger(typeof(Program)) // TODO: make this dynamic
);
```

So where I've done class Program, it needs to be the class its injecting it into. Please also beware that ILogger is NOT Microsofts logger, it is my own created ILogger interface, so `.AddLogging` wont work.

Comment: You can do assembly scanning. Just get the current executing assembly or the one you want and use LINQ to filter down to those who implement ILogger. If they have dependencies, then you might want to use a DI framework like Autofac.

Comment: I probably missed out the part/role of `Program` here. Can you tell us why the console logger needs the type Program? Usually you set everything up in your app's `Main()`. For Logging we actually use a simple singleton that proxies the logging to the ILoggers that we want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't want to change my DI framework, also I hear that reflection would be time-consuming seeing as a new instance is created for each class, no? I don't think its the best way to do this.

Comment: @DennisKuypers It needs whichever class the logger belongs to, its used for logging which class logged the message if its an error that was logged then for obvious reasons it drastically helps.

Comment: We have a singleton (well, we have static methods) `LogManager` that offers a `GetLogger(Type myType)` that returns an ILogger instance. This instance is a proxy that contains the `Type` it was created for. We than pass all the log information to the actual logger that in turn passes it to all `ILogOutput` instances that were registered. Also we do some filtering in between (levels and sources of logs). Maybe you can get inspired by an open source project like Log4Net. Your Console Logger would be an `ILogOutput` in my system.